# Leaflet: Force render a polyline for a marker outside of the bound

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to render a network topology on a world map and I am using LeafletJS to render the world map.

I draw edges or connections between 2 end points using the polylines feature of LeafletJS. I am also using clustering to cluster large sets of markers. The issue I am facing is that as users drill down/ zoom into a cluster, some polylines vanish because the endPoint1 is connected to endPoint2 and endPoint2 is out of the map area hence the polyline is not  drawn.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A code sample (as minimal as you can make it) reproducing your issue would greatly help.

Comment: Looks like you dynamically build your polylines. In your case it looks like the clustering feature interferes with your code. If you need further help with that code, you should share it.